# Is there a javascript library for ppt simulation?

Tags: javascript, slider, powerpoint

I do know that there're are many server side ppt simulation projects like Slide Show (S9).

But is there a javascript library which handles this and with a fairly easy syntax?

That would be more convenient as I don't see any perticular reason it needs to involve server side.

**UPDATE**

The final user should only be editing using the md-alike syntax,but Markdown doesn't incorporate page syntax.

By page,it's not normal paginator,but controlled with left/right arrow key.

Comment: Do you want to be able to create presentations, or just show them? If you want to be able to create _and_ save them, you'll have to use a server.

Answer (score 4):

- [Crocodoc](http://crocodoc.com/)
- [Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/)
- [SlideRocket](http://www.sliderocket.com/)
- [SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net/)
- Plain ol' PDF
- [reveal.js](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/)

Comment: I just tried several of them,it's not javascript library,but something like javascript workspace..

Comment: What exactly do you expect such a library to do if there is no server involved?

Comment: Actuallly I just want it to have : 1. markdown alike syntax 2. pages up/down.

Comment: This is nothing like a powerpoint simulation, then. Just combine a JS markdown parser and a client-side paginator.

Comment: The final user should only be editing using the md-alike syntax,but Markdown doesn't incorporate page syntax.

Comment: I would strongly recommend editing these requirements into your original question, since there's no mention of anything like markdown or pagination there.

Comment: Done~~pad~~~~~~~~~~         ~~:)

Answer (score 0):

Give [280Slides](http://280slides.com/) a try.

Also, I've been hearing a lot about [Prezi](http://prezi.com/) and [SlideRocket](http://www.sliderocket.com) in terms of online presentation creation, but not be what you're looking for.

Comment: The final user should only be editing using the md-alike syntax,not by workshop alike GUI stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you was looking for: [S5: Simple Standards-Based Slide Show System](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/)